# Returning multiple dequeueReusableCells in a TableView, Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

The problem I'm trying to solve is to return more than one cell for the loaded task, since i cannot iterate without getting a brand new task loaded.

Each view has one or more cell that is supposed to be loaded for that specific task and i can't seem to solve the problem. Thank you for helping out!

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let categoryCells = self.tasks[indexPath.row] as? Task
    var cellChooser: BoredTaskCell!

    if selectedTaskCategory == "Movie"{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("imdbCell") as! BoredTaskCell!
        cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cellChooser = cell
    }
    else if selectedTaskCategory == "Lifestyle" {
        let emailCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("emailCreatorCell") as! BoredTaskCell!
        emailCell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cellChooser = emailCell

    }
    else {
        let emptyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("messageCell") as! BoredTaskCell!
        cellChooser = emptyCell
        emptyCell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
    }

    return cellChooser
}
```

Comment: Where did you set `selectedTaskCategory`? Is it global variable?

Comment: Then after assigning the new value you just need to reload the tableView to show the updated cell.

Comment: Thanks for helping out Yogesh, i think i might have been a bit bad describing the problem. 

I want to be able to, for the same selectedTaskCategory to return more than one cellChooser, for example there would be a Task that needs to have both reusableCell "imdbCell" and also reusableCell "messageCell" and i want both of them to display when i reload the table (the tableView should return both cells at the same time pretty much) Hope it clear things up a bit! Also thanks again!

Comment: So you want to return more than 1 cell when `selectedTaskCategory` = `Movie`? Well It's not possible to return more than 1 cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because this method returns only 1 cell for 1 row. You need to create 1 cell with the info from `imdbCell` and `messageCell` cell. Then you will achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot return two cells from one call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  But to achieve what you want, change the way you construct the tableView, so it has one section for each task, rather than one cell for each task.  ie use `indexPath.section` as the index for your array.  You will need to amend all the table view data source methods (eg. so `numberOfSectionsInTableView` will return `self.tasks.count`).  The trick comes in `numberOfRowsInSection`, which should typically return 1, but for those tasks where you want two cells, it should return 2.  Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you determine which task to display using `indexPath.section`.  Then if indexPath.row is 0 use one cell type (eg imdbcell), and if it's 1 use the other cell type (eg message cell).